# WordConv.exe errors on Windows Server 2008 SP2

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, windows-server-2008-r2, documents

I am trying to convert MS-Word 2003 documents to the docx format as part of a larger programming effort.  Microsoft offers their [Office Compatibility Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3) as an option for this conversion.  As per the MS System requirements, MS Word does not have to be installed in order to use the utility; as the code will be run on a server, this is a desirable requirement.

To run the conversion with the compatibility pack:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\Wordconv.exe" -oice -nme "C:\source.doc" "C:\destination.doc"
```

When running this on Windows Server 2008 SP2 32-bit, the application crashes.  The following is logged to the Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application Wordconv.exe, version 12.0.6500.5000, 
time stamp 0x49a6d394, faulting module unknown, version 0.0.0.0, 
time stamp 0x00000000, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x00000000, 
process id 0x1bac, application start time 0x01cdf509762f5a4b.
```

Viewing the problem dialog details reveals the following information:

[image: 1]

I have tested this utility on a Windows 7 Box with Word 2010 installed with success; I have also had success when running this from a Windows Server 2003 SP2 32Bit without Word installed.

Any thoughts, insights or questions would be welcomed in trying to figure out the root cause of this issue.

### Solution:

In order to resolve this issue with Win Server 2008 SP2 32-bit, you have to install the 'Desktop Experience' Feature from the Server Manager console.
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/word-converter-compatible-server-2008-a-t3987185.html

Comment: Permission issue is a plausible explanation, however I am a local admin on the box.  I wasn't even aware of SuperUser.com since I am always here for my Development issues.; migration seems logical.

Comment: Local admin doesn't mean "gets all rights" any longer since UAC and Vista were released. Seems like an easy test to verify, though - move the files somewhere other than C:\ where you have write access (like C:\Users\YourName\Documents) and try the conversion there. If it works, it's the rights issue; if it doesn't, it isn't. :-)

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should avoid using automation server-side if at all possible because of these exact problems. Use a third-party library such as Aspose to properly perform the conversion on your server.

Comment: Adam, Thank you for that suggestion.  That suggesting was my next stop if I was unable to resolve this.